# Fixed Point Numbers Vs Floating Point Numbers

Tags: floating-point, floating, fixed-point

What are the various advantages/disadvantages from a computer architecture of fixed and floating point numbers? I can understand that both lead to inaccuracy of sorts.

My other questions are

1. How do these inaccuracies arise?
2. Is one form better than the other?

Answer (score 3):

From [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/):

> **Why floating-point numbers are needed**
>
> Since computer memory is limited, you
>   cannot store numbers with infinite
>   precision, no matter whether you use
>   binary fractions or decimal ones: at
>   some point you have to cut off. But
>   how much accuracy is needed? And where
>   is it needed? How many integer digits
>   and how many fraction digits?
>
> - To an engineer building a
>     highway, it does not matter whether
>     it’s 10 meters or 10.0001 meters wide - his measurements are probably not that accurate in the first place.
> - To someone designing a microchip,
>     0.0001 meters (a tenth of a millimeter) is a huge difference - But
>     he’ll never have to deal with a
>     distance larger than 0.1 meters.
> - A physicist needs to use the speed of
>     light (about 300000000) and Newton’s
>     gravitational constant (about
>     0.0000000000667) together in the same calculation.
>
> To satisfy the engineer and the chip
>   designer, a number format has to
>   provide accuracy for numbers at very
>   different magnitudes. However, only
>   relative accuracy is needed. To
>   satisfy the physicist, it must be
>   possible to do calculations that
>   involve numbers with different
>   magnitudes.
>
> Basically, having a fixed number of
>   integer and fractional digits is not
>   useful - and the solution is a format
>   with a floating point.

As for your other questions:

1. All inaccuracies arise because of exactly one reason: you're trying to fit an infinite amount of data (such as all rational numbers) into a limited space (such as 64 bits). The only thing that differs between formats is how the numbers that can be represented accurately are distributed.
2. Floating-point formats are better, period. They lack many of the limitations of fixed-point formants, though they still have many limitations (Pretty much all of which fixed-point formats *also* have).

That being said, the issue of floating-point vs. fixed point is often confused with binary vs. decimal - specifically, people often compare binary floating-point formats with (implicitly) decimal fixed point formats. Not being able to represent decimal fractions accurately is something that surprises most people and which they consequently consider a great disadvantage of "floating-point formats", when in reality it's a disadvantage of binary formats and they are not at all suprised at not being able to represent numbers like 1/3 accurately.

Comment: Your ideas intrigue me and I'd like to subscribe to your newsletter

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which programming language you are using, however, most programming languages do not have a built-in fixed point type.

Main stream languages like C and C++ have integer types and floating-point types. If you intend to use something like a fixed-point type with, say, four decimals, you would have to implement this on top of the existing integer types. Alternatively, use an existing library.

When it comes to the question which is better, the answer is "it depends". Things that you would have to consider are:

- What kind of hardware do you intend to use? Most modern host machines (PC:s) have dedicated floating-point hardware, likewise high-end embedded systems. However, when using a low-end embedded system it does not, so it must implement floating-point operations in terms of the existing assembler instructions.
- What is the nature of your application? Does it work naturally with, say, four decimals. What will happen if you get a rounding error on the least significant bit etc.